# Is there a way to re-order Git stashes?

Tags: git, git-stash

In Git one can make multiple stashes:

```
git stash save "quick temp stash"
git stash save "another quick temp stash"
git stash save "This is important but I need to put it on the back burner"
git stash save "This is almost certainly garbage, but just in case ..."
```

Now, I know that I can get those stashes back in any order:

```
git stash pop stash@{3} # recover quick temp stash
git stash pop stash@{2} # recover another quick temp stash
```

But obviously the more convenient syntax is preferable:

```
git stash pop
```

That's not just because there's less to type, but also because there's less thinking required: if I have several stashes I have to look through them, and maybe `git stash show` a couple, until I find the one I want.  But if I just keep the most recent "temp" stash at the top (followed by the next temp stash, etc.) I don't have to think at all; I just `pop`.

So, my question is, is there any way I can re-order my stashes, so that I can think about when they should be "popped" at the time I save them, rather than at the time I "pop" them.  This would allow me to still save "This is almost certainly garbage, but just in case ..." and "This is important but I need to put it on the back burner" stashes, but in the back of the stash list where they don't complicate accessing simpler quick stashes.

Comment: P.S. I do know that I *could* pop each stash off one at a time, commit each one, then rebase those commits in the desired order, then reset (soft) each one and convert it back in to a stash.  But not only is that really awkward, it potentially won't even work if the stashes come from different branches, so I'm hoping there's some other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in [Whymarrh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44142821/1256452) and [Donnie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142549/is-there-a-way-to-re-order-git-stashes#comment75306573_44142787), I think you're probably better served by just committing.  I will note, though, that:

> If you really wanted to keep using stashes and reorder those, you could adjust `refs/stash` as you work ...

It's possible to do this without using `git stash pop` at all.  It's just tricky.  (Edit: I see on re-reading that this was the idea in Whymarrh's answer.)

The *reflog* file, `.git/logs/refs/stash`, holds reflog entries 1 through *N* (however many exist).  The `stash` reference itself holds entry zero.

A `drop` operation consists of removing the specific reflog entry (`git reflog delete` knows how to handle the special zero case):

```
drop_stash () {
        assert_stash_ref "$@"

        git reflog delete --updateref --rewrite "${REV}" &&
                say "$(eval_gettext "Dropped \${REV} (\$s)")" ||
                die "$(eval_gettext "\${REV}: Could not drop stash entry")"

        # clear_stash if we just dropped the last stash entry
        git rev-parse --verify --quiet "$ref_stash@{0}" >/dev/null ||
        clear_stash
}
```

(where `clear_stash` deletes `refs/stash` itself).  The `$REV` argument is `refs/stash@{N}`, or `refs/stash` if you didn't specify a particular one.

The `store` operation inserts the entry at zero, using `git update-ref`:

```
[snip]
        w_commit="$1"
        if test -z "$stash_msg"
        then
                stash_msg="Created via \"git stash store\"."
        fi

        git update-ref --create-reflog -m "$stash_msg" $ref_stash $w_commit
        ret=$?
        test $ret != 0 && test -z "$quiet" &&
        die "$(eval_gettext "Cannot update \$ref_stash with \$w_commit")"
        return $ret
```

It's therefore possible, albeit a bit tricky, to achieve a "roll" operation (if you're familiar with Forth or Postscript).  To roll the bottom three entries up one step, for instance, changing:

```
E  stash@{4}
D  stash@{3}
C  stash@{2}
B  stash@{1}
A  stash@{0}
```

into:

```
E  stash@{4}
D  stash@{3}
B  stash@{2}
A  stash@{1}
C  stash@{0}
```

you would just copy `C` to the bottom, as if via a new `store`, then drop `stash@{3}` (which moved up because of the insertion at zero).

In fact, you can do this by running `git stash -q store` and `git stash -q drop`, with appropriate arguments.

Comment: Gonna need some time to re-read that and write an appropriate script (hopefully a nice simple one), but that all seems like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: What is interesting that with hated Mercurial MQ this is trivial task (like with `quilt`). I'd better dump `git stash list -p` and split patches and reapply them

Comment: @gavenkoa: I don't like `git stash` anyway. If I have more than one or two of them, I've done something wrong and should convert most or all of them to Git branches.

Comment: @torek That's true. Need to forget about `stash` and start using temporary branches. `stash` hides some operations, like no need for commit message and no need to separate checkout/rebase. But it is not a right tool to postpone work for a long time. And stacking of `stash` is nightmare ))

Answer (score 3):

Not out of the box—I don't think stash was really meant for that workflow.

That said, if you switch to temporary commits, you could reorder those commits as you saw fit and [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) commits (e.g. `git cherry-pick $tempbranch` as a replacement for `git stash pop`).

If you really wanted to keep using stashes and reorder those, you could adjust `refs/stash` as you work (via some scripting). From the [`git-stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> The latest stash you created is stored in `refs/stash`; older stashes are found in the reflog of this reference and can be named using the usual reflog syntax (e.g. `stash@{0}` is the most recently created stash, `stash@{1}` is the one before it, `stash@{2.hours.ago}` is also possible). Stashes may also be referenced by specifying just the stash index (e.g. the integer `n` is equivalent to `stash@{n}`).

If you decide to write a script for your workflow you also have `git stash create` and `git stash store` at your disposal:

> **create**
>
> Create a stash (which is a regular commit object) and return its object name, without storing it anywhere in the ref namespace. This is intended to be useful for scripts. It is probably not the command you want to use; see "save" above.
>
> **store**
>
> Store a given stash created via *git stash create* (which is a dangling merge commit) in the stash ref, updating the stash reflog. This is intended to be useful for scripts. It is probably not the command you want to use; see "save" above.

Comment: `create`/`store` are interesting, but `store` doesn't let you set the index of the stash either, so it seems to be as good/bad as `save` ... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I was offering `create`/`store` as options for scripting—they won't be much use at the command line. I've edited the answer to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: I did understand that you intended them for scripting, and I'm happy to write a script, but what I don't understand is how they (even when called from inside a script) could help solve the problem.  Even a script seems to have the same ultimate constraint, which is that you need to pop every stash in order to move any of them "to the back", so without a convenient way to do that (or a way to move stashes to the back without that) it seems impossible for a script to re-order stashes.

Answer (score 1):

> It's therefore possible, albeit a bit tricky, to achieve a "roll" operation (if you're familiar with Forth or Postscript).
> To roll the bottom three entries up one step, you would just copy C to the bottom, as if via a new store, then drop stash@{3} (which moved up because of the insertion at zero).

If you do this, make sure to use Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), as it would be too slow if you were to roll out a large number of commits.

"[`git stash drop`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a2fc9c3c404f2ef6384281e3a0fe824a8b0049bb/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L135)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-drop-q%7C--quietltstashgt))</sup> is reimplemented as an internal call to `reflog_delete()` function, instead of invoking "[`git reflog delete`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a2fc9c3c404f2ef6384281e3a0fe824a8b0049bb/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup>via `run_command()` API.

So instead of a subshell for each `stash drop` => `reflog delete`, all those `stash drop` calls remain in the same process, using internal functions.

See [commit 758b4d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/758b4d2be8c009a07dfa86d8cafdf1375905ab45), [commit 7d3d226](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d3d226e700904d6fbf3d9a1b351ebeb02f2cf04), [commit 76bccbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76bccbcfe2ff0d75302b0bf98b82aba95f8fc937) (02 Mar 2022) by [John Cai (`john-cai`)](https://github.com/john-cai).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a2fc9c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2fc9c3c404f2ef6384281e3a0fe824a8b0049bb), 16 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d3d226e700904d6fbf3d9a1b351ebeb02f2cf04): libify delete reflog function and helpers
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Cai</sup>

> Currently stash shells out to reflog in order to delete refs.
> In an effort to reduce how much we shell out to a subprocess, libify the functionality that stash needs into [`reflog.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d3d226e700904d6fbf3d9a1b351ebeb02f2cf04/reflog.c).
>
> Add a `reflog_delete` function that is pretty much the logic in the while loop in [`builtin/reflog.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d3d226e700904d6fbf3d9a1b351ebeb02f2cf04/builtin/reflog.c) `cmd_reflog_delete()`.
> This is a function that [`builtin/reflog.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d3d226e700904d6fbf3d9a1b351ebeb02f2cf04/builtin/reflog.c) and [`builtin/stash.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d3d226e700904d6fbf3d9a1b351ebeb02f2cf04/builtin/stash.c) can both call.